# Multiply values in column based on other column

Tags: r

I am new to R.
I want to multiply column of data frames. This type of questions must be very basic but I am new to R.I have input data as

```
Id  Name    quantity
Id1 Name1   200
Id2 Name2   300
Id3 Name3   500
Id4 Name4   400


Name    BonusMultiplier
Name1       1
Name2       2
Name3       3
Name4       2

Date        Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4
12/3/2014   20.5    200.3   56.3    550.6   
12/2/2014   21.5    180.3   60.5    556.2
12/1/2014   19.6    190.0   61.6    559.6
11/30/2014  15.6    195.6   62.6    580.8
```

Output I want should be like

```
Date        Name1       Name2           Name3       Name4
12/3/2014   20.5*200*1  200.3*300*2     56.3*500*3  550.6*400*2
12/2/2014   21.5*200*1  180.3*300*2     60.5*500*3  556.2*400*2
12/1/2014   19.6*200*1  190.0*300*2     61.6*500*3  559.6*400*2
11/30/2014  15.6*200*1  195.6*300*2     62.6*500*3  580.8*400*2
```

**EDIT**

What if output like

```
Date        Id1          Id2            Id3          Id4
12/3/2014   20.5*200*1  200.3*300*2     56.3*500*3  550.6*400*2
12/2/2014   21.5*200*1  180.3*300*2     60.5*500*3  556.2*400*2
12/1/2014   19.6*200*1  190.0*300*2     61.6*500*3  559.6*400*2
11/30/2014  15.6*200*1  195.6*300*2     62.6*500*3  580.8*400*2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `Map` (assuming that the datasets are ordered)

```
df3[,-1] <- Map(function(x,y,z) x*y*z, 
          df3[,-1], df2$BonusMultiplier, df1$quantity)

df3
#        Date Name1  Name2 Name3  Name4
#1  12/3/2014  4100 120180 84450 440480
#2  12/2/2014  4300 108180 90750 444960
#3  12/1/2014  3920 114000 92400 447680
#4 11/30/2014  3120 117360 93900 464640
```

Another option would be to `merge` (using `Reduce`) the datasets after converting the third dataset to `long` format with `melt`, then create the `mutliplied` column using `transform`, and finally convert the `long` form to `wide` format with `dcast`.

```
library(reshape2)
lst <- list(setNames(melt(df3, id.var='Date'), 
                c('Date', 'Name', 'value')), df1, df2)

 dcast(
      transform(
         Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Name'), lst),
           value=value*quantity*BonusMultiplier)[,1:3],
                          Date~Name, value.var='value')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tructure(list(Id = 1:4, Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", 
"Name4"), quantity = c(200L, 300L, 500L, 400L)), .Names = c("Id", 
"Name", "quantity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"), 
BonusMultiplier = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"BonusMultiplier"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df3 <- structure(list(Date = c("12/3/2014", "12/2/2014", "12/1/2014", 
"11/30/2014"), Name1 = c(20.5, 21.5, 19.6, 15.6), Name2 = c(200.3, 
180.3, 190, 195.6), Name3 = c(56.3, 60.5, 61.6, 62.6), Name4 = c(550.6, 
556.2, 559.6, 580.8)), .Names = c("Date", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", 
"Name4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But It did not work. :(. It is saying null value. I am trying to check. Seems your solution is correct. Along with I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish, you can just add a line `colnames(df3)[-1]<-df1$Id[match(colnames(df3)[-1],df1$Name)]` to get the Ids as colnames. Also, if your data.frames are not sorted, you can put `df1$quantity[match(colnames(df3)[-1],df1$Name)]` and `df2$BonusMultiplier[match(colnames(df3)[-1],df2$Name)]` as parameters of the Map function instead of just `df1$quantity` and `df2$BonusMultiplier`

Answer (score 1):

My version.

```
require(reshape2)

#create data
m1 <- data.frame(Id=paste0("Id", seq(1,4)), Name=paste0("Name", seq(1,4)),
quantity=c(2, 3, 5, 4)*100)
m2 <- data.frame(Name=paste0("Name", seq(1,4)), BonusMultiplier=c(1, 2, 3, 2))
m3 <- data.frame(rbind(c("12/3/2014", 20.5, 200.3, 56.3, 550.6),
                       c("12/2/2014", 21.5, 180.3, 60.5, 556.2),
                       c("12/1/2014", 19.6, 190.0, 61.6, 559.6),
                       c("11/30/2014", 15.6, 195.6, 62.6, 580.8)))
names(m3) <- c("Date", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4")

#do the work
m.melt <- melt(m3, id.vars="Date", variable.name="Name", value.name="Value")
m.all <- merge(merge(m.melt, m1), m2)
m.all <- within(m.all,
                answer <- paste(Value, quantity, BonusMultiplier, sep="*"))

dcast(m.all, Date ~ Name)
```

The output below

```
Date      Name1       Name2      Name3       Name4
1 11/30/2014 15.6*200*1 195.6*300*2 62.6*500*3 580.8*400*2
2  12/1/2014 19.6*200*1   190*300*2 61.6*500*3 559.6*400*2
3  12/2/2014 21.5*200*1 180.3*300*2 60.5*500*3 556.2*400*2
4  12/3/2014 20.5*200*1 200.3*300*2 56.3*500*3 550.6*400*2
```

Comment: Great, I would also had done it this way, but I think what Chaturvedi meant is to perform the calculation itself `answer <- Value*quantity*BonusMultiplier`

Comment: I guess I'm a WYSIWYG guy; that's what he displayed afterall ;)

and yes, your replacement of `answer` would help him get the calculation results instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here is a simple solution:
# Step 1: sort the three data frames according to 'Name'.
df1.1 <- df1[order(df1$Name), ]
df2.1 <- df2[order(df2$Name), ]
df3.1 <- df3[, c("Date", order(names(df3)[-1]))]

# Step 2: define a new data.frame named df3.2 to store the output
df3.2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(df3.1), nrow=nrow(df3.1)))
df3.2[, 1] <- df3.1[, 1]
names(df3.2) <- names(df3.1)

# Step 3. run a for-loop to calculate for each column of df3.1
for(i in 1:(ncol(df3.1)-1))
{
   j <- i+1
   df3.2[, j] <- df3.1[, j] * df1.1[i, "quantity"] * df2.1[i, "BonusMultiplier"]
}

head(df3.2)
```