# Multiply column of data frame as per value in another data frame

Tags: r

I am new to R.
 so this might be very basic question to ask

I have input data frames as

```
Id  State   quantity
1   State1  200
2   State2  300
3   State3  500
4   State2  400
```

and

```
Date        State1  State2  State3  
12/3/2014   20.5    200.3   56.3        
12/2/2014   21.5    180.3   60.5    
12/1/2014   19.6    190.0   61.6    
11/30/2014  15.6    195.6   62.6
```

Output I am trying to get as

```
Date            1           2               3           4
12/3/2014   20.5*200    200.3*300       56.3*500    200.3*400
12/2/2014   21.5*200    180.3*300       60.5*500    180.3*400
12/1/2014   19.6*200    190.0*300       61.6*500    190.0*400
11/30/2014  15.6*200    195.6*300       62.6*500    195.6*400
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiply values in column based on other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439113/multiply-values-in-column-based-on-other-column)

Comment: @CathG Thanks for checking it. It is returning state names as column in output. I wanted the Id. Id2 and Id4 has the same state. Almost same as per you link, but as I am new to R, these are different things to learn. :)

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  I updated the post.  Could you check if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 dfN <- data.frame(Date=df2$Date)
 dfN[paste0("Id", 1:4)] <- Map(function(x,y) x*y,
       df2[match(df1$State, colnames(df2))], df1$quantity)

 dfN
 #       Date  Id1   Id2   Id3   Id4
 #1  12/3/2014 4100 60090 28150 80120
 #2  12/2/2014 4300 54090 30250 72120
 #3  12/1/2014 3920 57000 30800 76000
 #4 11/30/2014 3120 58680 31300 78240
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:4, State = c("State1", "State2", "State3", 
 "State2"), quantity = c(200L, 300L, 500L, 400L)), .Names = c("Id", 
 "State", "quantity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))

 df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("12/3/2014", "12/2/2014", "12/1/2014", 
 "11/30/2014"), State1 = c(20.5, 21.5, 19.6, 15.6), State2 = c(200.3, 
 180.3, 190, 195.6), State3 = c(56.3, 60.5, 61.6, 62.6)), .Names = c("Date", 
 "State1", "State2", "State3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: It is returning state names as column in output. I wanted the Id. Id2 and Id4 has the same state.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  Sorry, didn't check it clearly

Comment: Updated code is working. But a problem. It is working in default R editor but if I use the same code in RStudio using +function in +different file it is giving NULL warning encountred, probably because of columns not defined in dfN. Any idea?

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  I guess you mentioned earlier regarding this NULL problem.  Have you tried that on R console?  I am using R console, so I don't know what might be the problem in RStudio.  In the `dfN`, I am creating new columns, with `dfN[paste0('Id'...`

Comment: On R console its fine. On RStudio I had the same problem earlier so I had to do it like this mydata["newcol"] <- NULL and then mydata$newcol <- value. Difference in using RConsole and RStudio for me is, in RConsole one statement at a time is copy/paste/exected while in RStudio I am defining it in a separate file and function and calling it

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish Thanks, I will download RStudio and check what went wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66751/discussion-between-chaturvedi-dewashish-and-akrun).